# How to add whatsapp like options to contact whenever the is a new contact added to Contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter, android-account, android-contact-mimetype

I develop an app which needs to do 2 things:

- Create a user account (like WhatsApp).
- Whenever there is a new contact entry, if the contact is using my app, then immediately in the Contacts application show options "call" or "message" in the contact detail page.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xibAK.png)

Comment: whenever you open the app, check for all contacts in your database, if its in your list, display! That should do right?

Comment: if you add any contact to contact list , even though whatsapp not running in the background , it will show options call to XXXXXX, message to XXXXXXX, this is what I need to achieve Checkout image attached.

Answer (score 9):

You need to create a `SyncAdapter`, this is basically a service that is able to sync contacts to/from a server, like `Google` does for `Google Contacts`, you can set it to be notified when a new contact is added, and have your `SyncAdapter` add the needed info to the contact so it'll show links to your app.

If you go to your phone settings > accounts, you can see `Whatsapp` and Google's `SyncAdapters` there, where you can turn them off/on.

To create a sync adapter, you can follow the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html), or this [great tutorial](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/).

Comment: The tutorial is actually great. Thanks

Comment: just a question though can we set sync adapter to notify when a new contact is added or you are talking about setting up contentobserver for the contacts base uri ? @marmor

Comment: This answer only explain how to create a SyncAdapter, and not how to add an option to a contact