# How to add intent to open my app in contact list?

Tags: android

I am working on a payment application. I want to add an option "pay to phone_number" in contact info of every contact like whatsapp as shown in the picture

[image]

In picture there is app icon along with "Message phone_number" similarly i want to show my app icon and then "pay to phone_number".

After some research i know that i have to add my application to account manager. But couldn't get how to specify the message i want to show after app icon and intent that i want to open.

Comment: i'm sorry, still not understanding your question. You want to open the app in the page when the app starts?

Comment: I want to open payment activity in my app, when user selects the option "pay to phone_number" from any contact.

Comment: by "any contact" you mean using the default contact app from the device?

Comment: yes, any contact in the default contact app of android. If you already have whatsapp installed in your device, Tap on any contact in contact application it will take you to a detailed view screen with options as shown in attached picture.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry, I understood the question now. Never tried that, but check this pages, see if it helps ;)

[How to add whatsapp like options to contact whenever the is a new contact added to Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525615/how-to-add-whatsapp-like-options-to-contact-whenever-the-is-a-new-contact-added)
[Display the app icon if the contact is associated with the application in phone address book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701017/display-the-app-icon-if-the-contact-is-associated-with-the-application-in-phone)

Comment: It's is possible just don't know how to do it. Several applications are already doing it and you can see three of them in attached picture.

Comment: You are right, edited my answer, see if it helps you @DarkShadow