# How to get app icon in android contact details like whatsapp ?

Tags: synchronization, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

How to get app icon in android contact details like whatsapp ?  how true-caller and whats-app similar way, on click of the icon i want to pass selected number to the app and show on textview .

Comment: What have you tried? What is your code?

Comment: Hi @Flummox i tried doing with this .  http://blogs.quovantis.com/syncing-contacts-with-an-android-application-2/

Comment: @imparhuri please update your question with the code, and possibly with the error messages.

Comment: @Flummox https://github.com/ajkh35/ContactsDemo this is the code i am trying but my problem is this code is not syncing with all the contacts

Comment: @Flummox please share me any resources related to this help me figure to out .

Comment: @impathuri please share (the relevant parts of) the code _within the question itself_, as per SO rules: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. External links can change or disappear over time, making the question useless for future readers.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for this i will do it .

Comment: @ADyson actually i need help for reference more then a code

Comment: Asking for references or tutorials is considered off-topic, and with good reason IMO - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for details.

Comment: @ADyson Reference to build code , to understand better way for the problem that to where i am stuck  with . And this is not off topic since its related to programming do understand my question please thanks for the updates regards SO.and my code which i has too many files included so i am asking for better solution to solve the above problem.

Comment: @impathuri right now your question _is_ off-topic as per the rules. The question doesn't simply have to be coding-related, it has to conform to certain quality standards. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic as I suggested, and also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . If you want an answer and to avoid your question being closed down you need to include your code, and not ask for links to tutorials etc.

Comment: @ADyson thanks i will update my post

Comment: see my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42642971/819355

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add whatsapp like options to contact whenever the is a new contact added to Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525615/how-to-add-whatsapp-like-options-to-contact-whenever-the-is-a-new-contact-added)